# Stripe Connect Fixed/Flat Fee based on value for Connected Accounts

Tags: stripe-payments

I am creating a Stripe Connect marketplace which charges a fixed fee based on value of sales, e.g. up to £2500 of revenue (for a connected account in a calendar month) will incur a flat fee of £200 per month to the platform.

I have read the Stripe documentation but still quite unclear how I can achieve this using a Standard Connect account. I understand the concept behind adding a flat fee per transaction but my use case is based around the amount of revenue over a time period.

Any help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

it sounds like you want to keep track of the payments processed by your connected accounts in order to figure out what to charge them.

The best way to do this is probably to set up a [Connect webhook](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/webhooks) and listen for [events](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-charge.succeeded) like `charge.succeeded` and keep a running total each month for each account.

You have a number of options for charging your accounts, but using Billing to [create a subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/creating) that you update as their revenue grows is probably the best experience. You could also use metered billing with [pricing tiers](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/metered-billing/thresholds#tiered-pricing) based on the payments you track.

If you need to calculate historic revenue, you'd need to manually [retrieve the payments](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list) and calculate the total for the month(s) you're interested in.

**NOTE:** For *both* the webhook events and the retrieval approaches you'd need to be aware of several different objects other than Charges that may affect revenue up or down, like [PaymentIntents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents), Refunds, Disputes etc depending on the details of the connect account's integration.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, the info is really useful here. One quick follow up - if e.g. payouts are every week (7 days), will there be any account credit left for a subscription to charge the account?

Comment: Since you control the payouts, you could ensure enough is left in an account balance at the right time for your recurring charge. If you didn't want to calculate it precisely, it could be an estimate and you delay the payouts so they are offset by a week or two or let the account carry a reserve balance (ie, don't payout to zero).